# passing array data from PHP to Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I am fetching an array from a MySQL result into a array variable. I can successfully use a simple php echo line in the javascript beneath to grab the first $row element, but I want to use json_encode to get the whole array at once.

When I do this and try to set a javascript var to the first array element something goes wrong and even the single var method stops working.

```
<?php
.
.
.
    while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM)) {
        $row1 = $row[0];
    }       
?>

<script type="text/javascript">  
    var RowArray = <?php echo json_encode($row); ?>;
    var RA1 = RowArray[0];
    window.alert(RA1);

    var Row1 = '<?php echo $row1; ?>';      
    window.alert(Row1);     
</script>
```

Comment: How about `$allRows = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_NUM);`? If not, what does the data look like and how do you want it represented in JavaScript?

Comment: If any of the rows consist non-UTF8 special characters. json_encode can return null. And will cause failing JS on var RowArray = ; (since PHP does not echo null but nothing when casted to a string) (The error will be a unexpected ;)

Comment: The fetch_all worked.  I'm not exactly sure why my fetch_array failed.  Maybe because of how the loop and the script timing are handled by the web server? But I am happy for a practical solution.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Make an array containing all the records:

```
$rows = [];
while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM))
{
   // do custom modifications to $row if neededed
   $rows[] = $row; // push to array
}
```

Or just:

```
$rows = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_NUM);
```

And then use `json_encode()` with `$rows`.